# Date format issue in ssis

Tags: excel, ssis

I have to import data from Excel file to SSIS but i am facing a problem in date column,in excel sheet date format is `yyyy/mm/dd` and when it gets upload in database it get change into `yyyy/dd/mmm` format.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the SUBSTRING function in the derived column while importing the date,

```
(LEN(TRIM(SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,1,8))) > 0 ? (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,1,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(ReceivedDateTime,7,2)) : (DT_DBDATE)NULL(DT_WSTR,5))
```

If the Data is there then use Substring function to extract the exact date that sets in the DB or if the date does not exist then insert NULL in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1. [Data Conversion Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141706.aspx) to convert to a text string in
   the appropriate format. Using SSIS data types.
2. Add a script task that converts the data type. Using VB data types

Answer (score 0):

First Create Table into Your Database Using below Command

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Manual] (
   [Name] nvarchar(255),
   [Location] nvarchar(255),
   [Date] datetime
   )
   SET DATEFORMAT YDM
```

By using **DATEFORMAT YDM** ,Date Will import in YYYY/DD/MM Format .Before runnung package modify the package and at the time of Column mapping select The Check Box  "Delete Rows in Destination Table" .

Then Execute the Package . It Will work .